# Easy script for making and overlaying video counters?

Tags: video-editor, effects, subtitles, plugins

I wanted to make a family of videos like

and I was wondering if there were any easy plugins/scripts to be able to create and increment the counter while watching a video. I envision something that operates like a little html/java script that increments on a keystroke as you run through the video, that you can later style something like CSS. I obviously am not saying it has to be exactly like this, but in essence I want to know if there are any bits bits of software like that. If not I might just try making it.

Comment: What exactly are you searching for, do you want to know what software to use to create similar videos or how to make this interactive in the browser?

Comment: I want a script that lets me easily create some like an .ass or .ssa subtitle overlay for when  I am producing videos. Let's say I'm using VLC, or maybe Lightworks. I watch a video and with the push of the button I increment a counter that corresponds to a number in some kind of soft sub. I say soft subs so that later I can go and adjust the styles of the subtitle.

Comment: Do you want to create this a subtitle just so you can adjust the styling at a later point?
Why would you want to adjust the style later on and not just finalize style in the video software and render it into the video like in the youtube video?

Comment: Looking back at your first comment, yes, can you list what software can easily make this effect.

Answer (score 1):

In that case Adobe After Effects can do this easily, which probably also produced the effect in the video.
It's actually the only software where I know you can do this without too much manual labor. Other products usually only offer a timer effect which would be tedious to use for these kind of things.

Though if you want to do this based on just a single key press and don't want to set keyframes manually you will have to write a script for After Effects, this can be done either via Adobe ExtendScript which is a subset of JavaScript or alternatively Windows Batch and Apple Script. I'd suggest using ExtendScript, it has better documentation and is relativley easy to use.

Be advised that this won't be a task that you can finish in 1-2 days if you haven't worked with After Effects yet. Especially the scripting part. Do it manually first and then look how you can automate it via a script.

Comment: what would people call this type of effect anyways: video counter/tallying/tracking?

Comment: I wouldn't say there is a specific name for it but usually you call that simply a counter

Comment: that was what i originally tried looking up but everywhere people are just asking about how to maximize their view counts for videos -_-

Comment: It's not something you do often, so googling this might be indeed a bit tricky. Maybe this question gets a good Google ranking so other don't have it so hard :P